# С#: как слушать 25ый порт на свой машине

Tags: c#, сокет, сокеты, клиент-сервер

Я пытаюсь вот что проделать:
написать консольное приложение, которое перехватывает мою же исходящую почту (25ый порт). Делаю это в виде виновс-сервиса.

```
var SMTP_Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 25);
SMTP_Listener.Start();
```

дальше я не понимаю что мне делать раньше. В инете полно литературы про диалог клиента с сервером, а про этот случай не нашел. Может я не верным путем пошел?

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении мене двигаться? Спасибо.**

Comment: Ну вам и нужен диалог клиента с сервером. Когда приходит входящее сообщение делаете accept (или как прием соединения в C# называется) пишете в сокет приветственное сообщение `220 имя-хоста версия мейл сервера и т.п.`, ждете входящего сообщения `HELO`, если все ок - шлете `EHLO` ну т.д. только это перехватом не назовешь, в настройках вашей почтовой программы в качестве smtp должен быть указан адрес на котором ваша программа ждет соединений (127.0.0.1 если вы на том же компе)

Comment: @Mike активацию сервера *smtp* инициализирует клиент а не сервер, поэтому перехватывать надо свои действия

Comment: @Dmitry Но он же пишет Listen, именно таким образом я принимаю входящие сообщения на свой почтовый фильтр, ну я 25 порт iptables заворачиваю на себя. А тут т.к. он под виндой и не понятно как завернуть порт надо что бы клиент подключился напрямую к его проге, вместо реального smtp-сервера. А для этого надо просто указать ее в настройках его почтового клиента

Comment: @Mike предположим что ТС пишет шпиона, и хочет отправлять своим слушателем почту на какой-то ящик, при этом не трогая клиента, то тогда ваш метод не поможет вообще ни как. но это в теории. Надеюсь все-таки ТС благоразумен и не собирается писать шпионов :)

Comment: @Dmitry Конечно не поможет, поэтому я и написал, что перехватом это назвать нельзя :) Ему в прошлый раз отлично ответили, что надо просто слушать весь проходящий трафик wincap'ом, но он же упорно продолжает делать listen ...

Comment: @Mike ну на самом деле можно это сделать и слушателем, например так http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530481/how-to-listen-on-port-25-with-vb-net если ТС захочет, может перевести VB в шарп

Comment: @Dmitry По вашей ссылке обычный слушатель, трафик она на себя не заворачивает а ждет пока клиенты сами подключатся

Comment: @Mike все верно, но трафик она таки себе скопировать может